# I have a number and I need to format it to billion or million

Tags: javascript, algorithm, formatting

I need a function which recive a number and return formated sum.
For expample: I have a number - 136866516683 this should return 136.87B(rounded).
Can you help?

this is what I have done:

```
function fnum(x) {
if(x < 1000000000) {
    return Math.round((x/1000000)) + "M";
}

if(x < 1000000000000) {
    return Math.round((x/1000000000)) + "B";
}

 return "More";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done a Google search on **["How to format numbers in JavaScript"](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+format+numbers+in+JavaScript&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS761US761&oq=How+to+format+numbers+in+JavaScript&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user doesn't appear to have tried anything and is just requesting a solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I had write this function but it returns without hundredths

Comment: Again, have you done the Google search that I've linked to?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: the discussions on Meta suggest that we mark such questions as "Too broad".  That has worked fine for me.

Comment: @Prune The reason is less important than the vote to close. But, in my case, I voted as "off topic"  because the question really isn't broad.  There is a particular way to do this. This issue isn't how to do what the OP is asking, the issue is that the OP hasn't made any effort to solve the problem on his/her own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals. 
Here is the JsFiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/zco2d5x1/

```
function fnum(x) {
  if (x < 1000000000) {
    alert((x / 1000000).toFixed(2) + "M");
  } else if (x < 1000000000000) {
    alert((x / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "B");
  } else
    alert("More");
}
fnum(136866516683);
```